# overflow-y in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

Is there any way by which we can simulate the `overflow-y: hidden` ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)) style in react-native StyleSheet?

Answer (score -1):

No need to use the overflow property if your views are well designed. Do not hesitate to encapsulate your views in many views as needed and make sure you're using flex boxes or static height/width, limit texts lengts with 'numberOfLines', etc

If you really need to hide an overflow in Y, manage your width properly and just use

```
overflow: hidden
```

to handle your height.